# Trouble understanding why assigning sorted array doesn't work in Explorer

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Sample code is sorting HTML, a list of names alphabetically.

This code works in all browsers:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Works in any current browser.</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Harald</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Filip</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Ivar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Gustav</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Ludvig</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Johan</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Kalle</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>&Ouml;sten</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Erik</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>&Aring;ke</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Viktor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Sigurd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>David</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Tore</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Bertil</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Cesar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Adam</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>&Auml;rlig</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Yngve</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Wilhelm</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Xerxes</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Z&auml;ta</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Urban</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Qvintus</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Olof</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Rudolf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Petter</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Niklas</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Martin</p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var lista = document.getElementsByClassName("klass");

    var nyLista = Array.prototype.slice.call(lista);


    nyLista.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText);


    });

    //DIFFERENCE STARTS HERE
    var explorerArray = [];

    for (i = 0; i < nyLista.length; i++) {
      explorerArray[i] = nyLista[i].outerHTML;

    }
    for (i = 0; i < explorerArray.length; i++) {
      lista[i].outerHTML = explorerArray[i];
    }
    //DIFFERENCE ENDS HERE
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This doesn't work in Explorer but in Chrome and Firefox and Edge:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Doesn't work in Explorer</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Harald</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Filip</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Ivar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Gustav</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Ludvig</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Johan</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Kalle</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>&Ouml;sten</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Erik</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>&Aring;ke</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Viktor</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Sigurd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>David</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Tore</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Bertil</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Cesar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Adam</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>&Auml;rlig</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Yngve</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Wilhelm</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Xerxes</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Z&auml;ta</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Urban</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Qvintus</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Olof</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Rudolf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Petter</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Niklas</p>
  </div>
  <div class="klass">
    <p>Martin</p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var lista = document.getElementsByClassName("klass");

    var nyLista = Array.prototype.slice.call(lista);


    nyLista.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.innerText.localeCompare(b.innerText);
    });


    //DIFFERENCE STARTS HERE
    for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
      lista[i].outerHTML = nyLista[i].outerHTML;
    }
    //DIFFERENCE ENDS HERE
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Can anybody explain why the latter code in Explorer fails to do it's job? 
In Explorer an incomplete list is returned. Tested with a couple of versions, currently on IE 11.0.9600.18666 and 11.296.15063.0. If it works in other versions. Please let me know.

Comment: Cause your html is malformed and it's only luck that it works anywhere.

Comment: I appreciate your input but it doesn't answer the question why the result is divergent in different browsers.

Comment: Actually yes it does, though I admit not as completely as you might like, which is why this is a comment and not an answer. If you don't properly form your HTML you cannot be guaranteed consistent behavior across browsers. What happens is that they have to make a "guess" as to what you intended to do. Generally that means IE is going to fail horribly. `<div>`s cannot be the direct child of a `<ul>`.  Also by not closing you `<li>` you are allowing IE to guess incorrectly what you intended. If you need the divs wrap the content inside the lis

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
I've corrected the code now and the JavaScript problem still remains in IE.

Comment: You need to be careful with `outerHTML`, because assigning it causes object references to it to potentially change. Since `getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* HTMLCollection, anything you do to modify the elements in the collection can cause problems. I think that's what you're seeing in IE; `lista` is a live collection, but `nyLista` is not. So IE gets all confused about what `lista[i]` is. It's a bit like splicing an array inside a for-loop; you're constantly changing the `length` and "bad things happen".

Comment: It's also why getting the `outerHTML` in a loop, then assigning in a separate loop works; there's no clash between the object references between `lista` and `nyLista`.

Comment: Thanks for you input. Logging shows that assingning to lista leaves nyLista with OuterHTML = <div class="klass"></div>

Comment: Problem remains if call a non live HTML collection for nyLista: var nyLista = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".klass"));